# Scraping images from a website into subfolders

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am trying to scrape images from this website: hhttps://moweek.com.uy/.

There are different subheaders: "VESTIMENTA", "CALZADO", "ACCESORIOS", "BEAUTY", "MARCAS", "AGENDA" & "BLOG". I want to "click" in "VESTIMENTA" and click into each subheader ("Activewear", "Blazers y chaquetas") as they look in the following picture but I am having trouble with a code that worked in the past:

[image]

My main goal is to download the images in each subheader (category) into a folder called "images" in a sub-folder with the category name (activewear, "blazer_y_chaquetas", etc). In the code, I want to download information from each picture, but now I have that separated in another script.

This is what I have so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

url <- "https://moweek.com.uy/"
html_content <- GET(url)

webpage <- read_html(content(html_content, as = "text"))

category_nodes <- html_nodes(webpage, "a.headerOption.headerLink[data-category-id='1']")
category_urls <- html_attr(category_nodes, "href")

dir.create("images", showWarnings = FALSE)

# Loop through subcategories and download images
for (category_url in category_urls) {
  # Remove any extra slashes in the URL construction
  subcategory_url <- paste0(url, gsub("/+", "/", category_url))
  
  subcategory_page <- tryCatch({
    read_html(subcategory_url)
  }, error = function(e) {
    message(paste("Error accessing URL:", subcategory_url))
    return(NULL)
  })
  
  if (is.null(subcategory_page)) {
    next  # Skip to the next subcategory if an error occurred
  }
  
  subcategory_name <- subcategory_page %>% html_text()
  
  # Clean the subcategory name for folder creation
  subfolder_name <- gsub(" ", "_", tolower(subcategory_name))
  subfolder_path <- file.path("images", subfolder_name)
  dir.create(subfolder_path, showWarnings = FALSE)
  
  # Extract image URLs and download them into the subfolder
  image_urls <- subcategory_page %>% 
    html_nodes(".your-image-selector") %>%
    html_attr("src")
  
  for (image_url in image_urls) {
    image_name <- basename(image_url)
    download.file(image_url, file.path(subfolder_path, image_name))
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Paula! what is the issue with your code as it is? do you have an error code you receive, or are you more stuck on how to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly!

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, rvest, httr)

url <- "https://moweek.com.uy"
webpage <- httr::GET(url)

webpage <- read_html(content(webpage, as = "text"))

category_nodes <- html_nodes(webpage, ".expandedCategory")

category_urls <- lapply(category_nodes, function(node) html_nodes(node, "a") %>%
                          html_attr("href")) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  str_subset("vestimenta") %>%
  str_replace_all("1", "30")

category_urls <- category_urls[!(category_urls %in% c("/vestimenta/30",          "/vestimenta/activewear/30",
                                                      "/vestimenta/bodywear/30", "/vestimenta/leggings-y-bikers/30",
                                                      "/vestimenta/lenceria/30", "/vestimenta/hombre/30",
                                                      "/vestimenta/ninos/30",    "/vestimenta/pijamas-y-camisones/30",
                                                      "https://moweek.com.uy/vestimenta/vestidos/30",
                                                      "https://moweek.com.uy/vestimenta/trajes-de-bano/30"))]

dir.create("images", showWarnings = FALSE)

# Function to limit folder name length
limit_folder_name_length <- function(category_url, max_length = 50) {
  # Extract the subcategory name from the category_url
  subcategory_name <- gsub(".*/vestimenta/(.*?)/30", "\\1", category_url)
  
  if (nchar(subcategory_name) > max_length) {
    subcategory_name <- substr(subcategory_name, 1, max_length)
  }
  return(subcategory_name)
}

# Loop through subcategories and download images
for (category_url in category_urls) {
  
  subcategory_name <- gsub(".*/vestimenta/(.*?)/30", "\\1", category_url)
  subfolder_name <- limit_folder_name_length(gsub(" ", "_", tolower(subcategory_name)))
  subfolder_path <- file.path("images", subfolder_name)
  dir.create(subfolder_path, showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
  
  subcategory_url <- paste0(url, gsub("/+", "/", category_url))
  
  # Sleep for a few seconds to avoid overloading the server
  Sys.sleep(3)
  
  cat_content <- RETRY("GET", subcategory_url)
  cat_page <- read_html(content(cat_content, as = "text"))
  
  image_urls <- cat_page %>%
    html_nodes(".productViewTopImage") %>%
    html_attr("src")
  
  image_urls <- ifelse(substr(image_urls, 1, 8) != "https://", paste0(url, image_urls), image_urls)
  
  for (image_url in image_urls) {
    if (!is.na(image_url) && image_url != "") {
     
       image_name <- basename(image_url)
      image_path <- file.path(subfolder_path, image_name)
      
      # Download and save the image to the subfolder
      download.file(image_url, image_path, mode = "wb")
      
    }
  }
}
```